# How to return only aggregation stats in an ElasticSearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to exclude documents from an aggregation query? I just need to know "count" and "sum" and do not need hits. I did it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {

    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_agg": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "country_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform Elasticsearch aggregation without returning hits array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467835/perform-elasticsearch-aggregation-without-returning-hits-array)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add to your query `?search_type=count`.
For example:

```
GET /my_index/countries/_search?search_type=count
{
"query": {
    "match_all": {

    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_agg": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "country_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "Deprecated in 2.0.0-beta1: count does not provide any benefits over query_then_fetch with a size of 0." [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#count)

Answer (score 14):

To focus only on aggregation with a match_all query, you could simply use "size":0 (this specifies you want no query results) with no query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/indexname/doctype/_search" -d'
{
    "size": 0, 
    "aggs": {
        "my_agg": {
            "stats": {
                "field": "country_id"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Actually, Andrei Stefan's answer is better (source : http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-aggregations.html#_returning_only_aggregation_results). However, no need to add the match_all query.