# Perform Elasticsearch aggregation without returning hits array

Tags: elasticsearch

Im using ES 1.4.  When I perform an aggregation, the result returns the hits array as well.  Is there a way to only return the aggregations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible. You should type additional Parameter (**?search_type=count**) in your Url. Have a look here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_returning_only_aggregation_results

Comment: The new documentation link is here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/returning-only-agg-results.html

And it recommends the `"size": 0` approach

Answer (score 60):

You would have to specify in the query that the size is equal to 0

ex :

```
{ 
    "query": ... ,
    "aggs": ... ,
    "size": 0
}
```

Related doc page on ES website: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/returning-only-agg-results.html